# css first-letter выше или ниже

Tags: css, stylus, first-letter

Как можно с помощью **css/stylus** поднять или опустить первую букву в блоке?

```
label {
  display: block;
}

label::first-letter {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding-top: -10px;
}
```

Так ничего не работает.

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант

```css
label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
}
label::first-letter {  
  color: tomato;
}
.bottom::first-letter{
    vertical-align: sub;
}
.top::first-letter{
    vertical-align: super;
}
```

```html
<label class="bottom">Text label</label>
<label class="top">Text label</label>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это хорошо, но для верстки пиксель-в-пиксель нужно, в моем случае, чуть ниже с `super`...

Comment: тогда так https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/m0upLLfL/

Comment: да, точно можно в `span` оборачивать... но в этом и сложность вопроса, что бы применить позиционирование именно к первой букве предложения без спец. добавлений